# Proving the square root of 2 exists(Possible typo in Zorich's Mathematical Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

In the picture above, I don't understand how if $$s^2 \lt 2$$ then $$\left (s + \frac{2-s^2}{3s}\right)^2 \lt 2$$ holds. What insures that $(s + \frac{2-s^2}{3s}) \in X = \{x : x^2 \lt 2\}$ where $x$ is a positive real number ??
And when the identity is expanded should it not be $$\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2=s^2+2\cdot s \cdot\frac\Delta{3s}+\left(\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2$$ instead of $$\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2=s^2+ 2 \cdot\frac\Delta{3s}+\left(\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2$$
 Thanks in advance!

P.S. The book is Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I in case this is an error.

Comment: The "$\frac{2- s^2}{3s}$ on the left is inside the $(  )^2$.  On the right it is not so what you think it "should be" does not follow.   Did you look at what you get if you actually **square** $s+ \frac{2- s^2}{3s}$?

Comment: @user247327 Yeah I just caught that too. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the definition of $X$ to the body of your Question, esp. since you are asking about why the expression $s + \frac{2-s^2}{3s}$ belongs to $X$.  It is hard to read the "picture" but as I make it out, $X = \{x\in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 \lt 2 \}$.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the tip but the book says that set $X$ is a set of positive real numbers whose squares are less than 2.

Comment: If we can assume $(\frac {\triangle}{3s})^2 < \frac {triangle}3$ and we assumee the s in the denominator was a typo, we are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $1 < s^2 < 2$ so $0 < 2- s^2 = \triangle < 1$.  So $ \frac{\triangle}{3s} < \frac {\triangle}3 < \triangle < 1$ so $(\frac{\triangle}{3s})^2 < \frac{\triangle}{3s}$.

That's the groundwork.

So $(s + \frac {2-s^2}{3s})^2 = (s + \frac {\triangle}{3s})^2$

$= s^2 + 2s*\frac {\triangle}{3s} + (\frac {\triangle}{3s})^2$

$< s^2 + 2*\frac {\triangle}3 + \frac {\triangle}3$

$= s^2 + 3\frac {\triangle}3 = s^2 + \triangle$

$= s^2 + (2 - s^2) = 2$.

So $s^2 < (2+ \frac {2-s^2}{3s})^2 < 2$.

And that's that.

(the book had a typo but they didn't make any conclusions based on it.  They forgot to cancel out the lower $s$ and left it in for a few steps, and then, simply had it disappear.  It was probably a type-setting error and not an actual error of the author.)

Or if you want to do it without the gordang triangle.

$(s + \frac {2-s^2}{3s})^2 = s^2 + 2s*\frac {2-s^2}{3s} + \frac {(2-s^2)^2}{9s^2}$

$=s^2 + \frac {4 - 2s^2}3 + \frac {4 - 4s^2 +s^2}{9s^2}$

$=s^2 +\frac 43 - \frac {2s^2}3 + \frac 4{9s^2} -\frac 49 + \frac {s^2}9$

$= \frac {4s^2}9 + \frac 89 + \frac 4{9s^2}$

$=\frac 49(s^2 + \frac 1{s^2} + 2)$

$= \frac 49(2 -h + \frac 1{2-h} + 2)$

$< \frac 49(2 + 1/2 + 2) = \frac {18}9 = 2$.

Comment: The typo that I noticed was $s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}<s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}$. The author was evidently having a bad day.

Answer (score 1):

$$s+\frac{2-s^2}{3s}=\frac{2+2s^2}{3s}=\frac 23 \cdot \left( s+ \frac 1s\right)$$

Now the function $ \left( s+ \frac 1s\right)$ is increasing in the interval $[1,\sqrt 2)$. Hence, its maximum value will occur at $s=\sqrt 2$

$$s+\frac{2-s^2}{3s}=\frac 23 \cdot \left( s+ \frac 1s\right)<\left[\frac 23 \cdot \left( s+ \frac 1s\right)\right]_{s=\sqrt2}=\sqrt 2$$

Finally,

> $$\left(s+\frac{2-s^2}{3s}\right)^2<2$$

Comment: @Red I have corrected everything now.

Comment: But you can't say "the interval $[1,\sqrt 2)$" and "its maximum value will occur at $s=\sqrt 2$" when the aim is to prove the _existence_ of $\sqrt 2$!

Comment: @TonyK I had a hunch what TonyK said might come up as a problem. So would it be possible to set the choice of $s+ \frac{2-s^2}{3s}$ both equal to and greater than 2 and show that both yield contradictions??

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the book. Instead of
$$\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2=s^2+2\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}+\left(\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2<s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}<s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}=s^2+\Delta=2$$
it should read something like:
$$\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2=s^2+2\cdot\frac\Delta{3}+\left(\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2<s^2+\left(2+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}<s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}=s^2+\Delta=2$$
Is it clear now?

Comment: I believe you've mistyped. And I dont see how that justifies that the element in question is a member of X?

Comment: If I've mistyped, I don't see it. But anyway the gist is that $\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2<2$, which is precisely the criterion for $s+\frac\Delta{3s}$ to belong to $X$.

Comment: I was referring to the fact you got in $s^2+\left(2+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}+<s^2+3\cdot\frac\Delta{3s}=s^2+\Delta=2$ a plus sign next to the less than sign. And when you(and the book) expanded  $\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2$ shouldn't it be $\left(s+\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2=s^2+2\cdot s \cdot\frac\Delta{3s}+\left(\frac\Delta{3s}\right)^2$ ?? Unless there is some algebraic manipulation I am not seeing!

Comment: You definitely have the same typo the book has $(s + \frac {\triangle}{3s})^2 = s^2 + 2s\cdot\frac {\triangle}{3s} + (\frac {\triangle}{3s})^2$.  You and the book have the $s$ is the denominator of the second term but not in the coefficient.  The $s$es cancel but the book left it in for two steps and then had it disapear.  You kept it in and manipulated it when it can't still be there.

Comment: @fleablood Do you think it is possible that the choice of $ \left (s + \frac{2-s^2}{3s}\right)^2$ is flawed, to begin with? Because I am having a really hard time following the proof.

Comment: No, I think it is fine.  $\triangle < 1$ and $s > 1$ so $(\frac {\triangle}{3s})^2 < \frac {\triangle}{3s} < \frac {\triangle}3$.  So $s^2 + 2s*\frac {\triangle}{3s}  + (\frac {\triangle}{3s} )^2 = s^2 +2*\frac {\triangle}{3} + (\frac {\triangle}{3s} )^2< s^2 +2*\frac {\triangle}{3} +  \frac {\triangle}3 = s^2 + 3\frac{\triangle}3 = s^2 + \triangle$.  It works but it's kind of inefficient.